# Reference request for robust statistics

Tags: self-study, estimation, references, robust

I'm trying to learn about robust statistics, one of the books that I saw about this topic is [Robust Statistics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470129905), but I have not found this book nowhere.

Does anyone know of any material that covers the same topics as the book, some alternative reference? College Material?

The contents of the book can be seen here [Table of Contents](http://www.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0470129905.html).

Comment: Maybe you can read a Microeconometrics book as in microeconometrics researchers often test for robustness. Peter J. Hubert, one of the two authors of the book, is well known for his research in the field of Microeconometrics.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would not start with Huber's book, even with its 2009 revision, unless you possess strong mathematical background, i.e. measure theory and topology. The book by Maronna and Yohai entitled [Robust Statistics: Theory and Methods](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470010924) is much more accessible for beginners and covers both univariate and multivariate theory, along with the computational aspects of the estimators (Chapter 9). So it is more modern in that respect.

Alternatively, if you find their book too easy but Huber's book still difficult there exists an intermediate alternative called [Robust Statistics: The Approach Based on Influence Functions](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471735779) from Frank Hampel and co-authors (Hampel was the person who invented the influence function). The mathematical requirements are more modest and there is substantial motivation for the estimators.

All these books may be found in digital libraries but if you still have trouble obtaining pdf versions, you might want to try [these notes](http://www.rci.rutgers.edu/~dtyler/ShortCourse.pdf), which are a fusion of all three books. You might also be pleased to know that all robust estimators exist in up-to-date R-packages, e.g. robustbase.

Answer (score 2):

Maronna's book from 2006, titled "Robust Statistics: Theory and Methods" is a very good introduction to the topic that covers roughly the same as Huber's. Depending on what aspect you want to touch on, I would focus on articles written by both Huber and Maronna to better help you understand how the field was developed.